# Using RMI with JSP

Tags: jsp, rmi

I am trying to use RMI with JSP. My code is as follows:

Hello.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.rmi.Remote" %>
<%@ page import="java.rmi.RemoteException" %>
<%!
public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
%>
```

Client.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry" %>
<%@ page import="java.rmi.registry.Registry" %>
<%@ include file="Hello.jsp" %>
<%!
public static class Client {

    public static String get() {

        String host = "<server's ip>";
        String res = null;
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            res = stub.sayHello();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res = ("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
%>
<%
out.println(Client.get());
%>
```

Server.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.rmi.registry.Registry" %>
<%@ page import="java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry" %>
<%@ page import="java.rmi.RemoteException" %>
<%@ page import="java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject" %>
<%@ include file="Hello.jsp" %>
<%!
public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {}

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

}
%>
<%
        try {
            Server obj = new Server();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);

            out.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Failed: "+e.toString());
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
%>
```

I am running this on a ubuntu tomcat server and I am getting the following error from the server:

> Client exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy27 cannot be cast to org.apache.jsp.src.rmi.Client_jsp$Hello

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I've never tried RMI in JSP (simply because it makes design technically no utter sense --you're basically using the wrong tool for the job), so I can't answer this from experience, but I strongly suspect that this problem has to do with incorrectly putting Java code in a JSP file instead of in normal Java classes, hereby making it harder for reflection to create proxies. I suggest to put that Java code in normal Java classes (and interfaces) and then retry it. Use a simple [servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) to test it. JSP should be used for generating HTML only.

Comment: Your design makes no sense. The server will only be present if the page hosting it has been visited. A new one will be created every time it is visited. After the first visit, all the subsequent binds will fail. Why a JSP page would host an RMI server is a mystery to me.